# ExtJs 4 combobox with checkboxes

Tags: combobox, custom-controls, extjs4, checkbox

I'm looking for EXTJS4 combobox control which allows selecting multiple items via checkboxes inside.

Actually I need this control http://lovcombo.extjs.eu/ but it is implemented for ExtJs3. I tried to convert it to ExtJs4 but the task is not trivial actually.

Could you suggest similar component for ExtJs4. Or maybe you could point me to some tutorial or example - how to do such things?

Answer (score 18):

Multiselect combo with checkbox in ExtJS4.0 can be achieved with addition few lines of code.

Basically you need to make use of the existing css class which get applied during selection and deselection of an item and pushing an image (checkbox image) at that time accordingly.

"**x-boundlist-item**" and "**x-boundlist-selected**" are the classes taken from ext-all.css.

```html
<style>
```

```css
.x-boundlist-item img.chkCombo {
    background: transparent url(/lib/extjs-4.1.0/resources/themes/images/default/menu/unchecked.gif);
}
.x-boundlist-selected img.chkCombo{
    background: transparent url(/lib/extjs-4.1.0/resources/themes/images/default/menu/checked.gif);
}
```

```html
</style>
<head>
```

```js
Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox', {
        id: 'BCCAddress',
        name: 'BCCAddress',
        maxHeight: 150,        
        width: 210,
        multiSelect: true,
        emptyText : "Select Bcc email addresses",
        renderTo: 'extBCCAddress',
        store: myArrayStore,
        displayField: 'fieldName',
        valueField: 'fieldName',
        forceSelection: true,
        editable: false,
        mode: 'local',
        triggerAction: 'all',
        listConfig : {          
            getInnerTpl : function() {
                return '<div class="x-combo-list-item"><img src="' + Ext.BLANK_IMAGE_URL + '" class="chkCombo-default-icon chkCombo" /> {fieldName} </div>';
            }
        }
    });
```

[below is an image of this custom component]
[image]

Comment: I'm using v4.2.1.883 (not sure if it matters) but the above code did not work until I added a height and width of 16px to each of the styles above. I also moved the image to my /Images directory (not sure if that mattered).  I'm really wondering what would be a better way to do this so that you don't have to hard code reference to the extjs resource path?

Comment: In ExtJS 4.2.1 (and other versions probably), you don't have to hard code the resource path. Instead, put the styles to a SCSS file (ex. sass/etc/all.scss) and use "background: transparent url(images/menu/checked.gif);". It appears that in 4.2.1, we have to explicitly give a width and height of 16px as Peter mentioned.

Comment: @PeterKellner says, You have to add height and width of 16px to your style. It is worked at me on extjs 4.2.2.

Answer (score 7):

1. use this: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?134751-Ext.ux.form.field.BoxSelect-Intuitive-Multi-Select-ComboBox

[image]

2. or this: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?132328-CLOSED-ComboBox-using-Grid-instead-of-BoundList

-- use grid with checkboxselectmodel in combox

Comment: I saw this component, and I think it is great. But I need exactly combobox with checkboxes. It is a requirement. Thanks anyway.

Comment: try the second way. or wait for a moment, there will be someone to move lovcombo to 4.x :)